# Setting conf var dynamically in laravel

Tags: laravel

How i can set dynamically the Conf variables for multi tenants app in Laravel? Is correct set in database and call config::set in boot() method in the AppServiceProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can add it in Service Provider config::set() method and config() helper.

Example with using config helper

```php
config([
     'keyConfig'=>['api_key'=>'api-key'],
]);
```

then you can use config('keyConfig.api_key')